# Counting the largest sequence of even numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the largest sequence of even digits in a number I input, find its index and the sequence of even digits itself.

I'm only starting to learn to program so I'm only in the sketch phase, this is what I thought of:

```
Split the number to a list of single digits. 

Apply modulo 2 to all digits. 

Count where is the biggest sequence of zeros. 

Take its index. 

From the index extract the original from the starting number.
```

My problem now is the str.split() function, what it does is to remove the split character, I also have to specify all 10 digits for it to split every digit.

Is there another function that do what I need for the first step or do I need to think it over ?

Note: I use python 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nums = str(12344444442)
from itertools import groupby as gby
if all (int(num) % 2 for num in nums):
    print("All are Odd numbers")
else:
    m_list=max((list(g) for n,g in gby(nums,key=lambda x:int(x)%2) if not n),key=len)
    # ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '2']   Longest even sequence
    print(nums.index("".join(m_list)))
    # 3   Starting index
```

Comment: This will print the longest sequence of digits with the same parity, which isn't necessarily even. (Just add `if not num` to the generator expression.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment thefourtheye's code, but that doesn't work with a nums like :

```
nums = str(155555555344444442)
```

Or :

```
nums = str(155555555)
```

I found a simple method using re.
It can return all identiques len of sequences.

```
import re
nums = str(22554442266)
groups = sorted([(len(n.group(0)), n.group(0), n.span(0)[0]) for n in re.finditer('(\d)\\1+', nums)], reverse=True)

results = [(groups[0][1], groups[0][2])] # Sequence, index
for n in groups[1:] :
    if n[0] != groups[0][0] :
        break
    results.append((n[1], n[2]))
print(results) # => [('444', 4)]
# nums = str(1112255566622111) => [('666', 8), ('555', 5), ('111', 13), ('111', 0)]
# nums = str(1112222333) => [('2222', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is list()

```
nums = 1423341
list(str(nums))
=> ['1', '4', '2', '3', '3', '4', '1']
```

Since you say you are just getting started, using the basic methods to just do what you are trying to do might be better than using lambdas and whatnot.

Comment: Did you mean ... list(str(nums))?

Comment: Definitely did, I copied and pasted in from the wrong code. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah those lambdas are a bit advanced.

Comment: Now that I think about, why change it to a string ? can I just split the number to digits ?

Comment: I think the numbers would have to be turned into a string one way or another for the split to happen. You could, however, do something like: `nums = 1423341
>>> [int(i) for i in str(nums)]
>>> [1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1]` which would return it as a list of integers.